# 2014 Harley Ultra Exhaust Upgrades

Tags: engine, motorcycle, exhaust, harley-davidson

I'm helping a buddy. He has a 2014 Harley Ultra Classic with a high output 103. It has 23k miles, Vance & Hines Short Slashes, Vance & Hines Heavy Sucker air filter, and Vance & Hines Fuel Pack Tuner. We are taking the baffles out of the exhaust and are wanting to see if we need to do anything else. Can these modifications do any engine damage?

Answer (score 0):

Of those modifications, I think the only one the possibly could cause damage would be the fuelpak tuner, but even it really shouldn't if used properly. The exhaust mods and air filter won't damage anything.